# How to Convert date into MM/DD/YY format in C#

Tags: c#, date

In My Asp.net webpage I need to display today's date into one of the textbox , so in my form load  I wrote the following code

```
textbox1.text = System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
```

this line is giving me date like 1/7/09  but I want date like 01/07/09  , Is there anyway I can conver this date into mm/dd/yy format  in C#?

Comment: This page is a great reference for string formatting in C#: http://blog.stevex.net/index.php/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
 DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yy")
```

Look at the docs for [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more info.

(Oh, and I hope this app isn't destined for other cultures. That format could really confuse a lot of people... I've never understood the whole month/day/year thing, to be honest. It just seems weird to go "middle/low/high" in terms of scale like that.)

Comment: I absolutely agree on the wierdness thing, although it's more likely my UK upbringing that makes dd/MM/yy more sensible to me.

Comment: Well both yy/MM/dd or dd/MM/yy have consistency in their favour - they're either going up or down the significance scale.

Comment: yyyyMMdd is year 2000 compliant and will sort into order nicely... it gets my Vote.

Comment: I've actually never understood why other countries use dd first.  I agree the yy/MM/dd would be optimal, but can't understand the value or significance of MM/dd.  When someone asks your date of birth in the UK, do you say January 1st 1970 or 1 January 1970.  The latter just seems silly.

Comment: @Matt: I vary - I either say "the 19th of June" or "June 19th", pretty interchangably.

Comment: MM/dd makes a lot of sense if you are keeping records on paper (most->least significant). Most records would be kept in annual batches, therefore the year is not relevant in terms of the record keeping (all the data is from the same year). When you start collecting more data and need to start keeping track of the year, it is a simple process to just "tack on the year" after the fact: MM/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 8):

> DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yy")
>
> Look at the docs for custom date and time format strings for more info.
>
> (Oh, and I hope this app isn't destined for other cultures. That format could really confuse a lot of people... I've never understood the whole month/day/year thing, to be honest. It just seems weird to go "middle/low/high" in terms of scale like that.)

Others cultures really are a problem. For example, that code in portugues returns someting like 01-01-01 instead of 01/01/01. I also don't undestand why...

To resolve that problem i do someting like this:

```
        IFormatProvider yyyymmddFormat = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(String.Empty, false);
        return date.ToString("MM/dd/yy", yyyymmddFormat);
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the following?:

```
textbox1.text = System.DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
```

Be aware that 2 digit years could be bad in the future...

Comment: @Herbert hahaha yes, it... will... be replaced by then. What he said ^^ :D

Comment: clean up on server side with one line of code and no messy javascript, nice.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method with a specified format.

Answer (score 0):

See, here you can get only date by passing a format string.
You can get a different date format as per your requirement as given below for current date:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
```

> **Result :** "9/1/2016"

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M-d-yyyy");
```

> **Result :** "9-1-2016"

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

> **Result :** "2016-09-01"

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

> **Result :** "2016-09-01 09:20:10"

For more details take a look at [MSDN reference for Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)