# To convert from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I used the following code.

```
string result = DateTime.ParseExact("24/5/2009 3:40:00 AM",
                                    "d/M/yyyy h:mm",
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        .ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm");
```

> In my textbox time after 12'0 Clock(
>   for eg:24/5/2009 14:00 ) i want to
>   convert to format as 24/5/2009 2:00
>   PM.Can anybody give appropriate code?

Comment: Is this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420623/how-to-convert-date-into-mm-dd-yy-format-in-c ?

Comment: No it's not, that question deals only with formatting a date as output, not converting from 1 format to another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim result As String = DateTime.ParseExact("24/5/2009 3:40:00 AM",
                                    "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                               .ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt")
```

See also:

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)
- [.NET String Formatting Cheat Sheet](http://acodingfool.typepad.com/blog/dotnet-string-formatting-cheat-sheet.html)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your original date starts as a string and you want it to end up as another string, you could do something like this in C#:

```
string from = "24/5/2009 3:40:00 AM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(from, "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string to = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

*Edit: Fixed the formatting strings.  It assumes your original strings only have single digit day, month, and hour values when they are each less than 10.  It also assumes you want them all to be 2 digit values for the result.

Here's the MSDN Documentation on the subject: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: You will want to add System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture as the second parameter of the dt.ToString call in order to ensure that the formatted string does indeed use '/' characters:
string to = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ff tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: The formatting string is wrong. "ff" is not seconds, it's seconds fraction. You need to use "ss" to get the seconds.

Answer (score 0):

A `DateTime` value doesn't have a format at all, so if the source is a datetime value it's not actually a conversion but a just matter of formatting the output.

You can use the custom foratting string `"M'/'d'/'yyyy h':'mm':'ss tt"` to get exactly that format. (Your question mentions two different formats, so I assume that it's the one represented by the example data that you want; the one that has seconds.)

Example:

```
Dim result As String = source.ToString("M'/'d'/'yyyy h':'mm':'ss tt")
```

If the source is a string so that it's actually a conversion that you need, you can either use string operations to chop up the string into components and rearrange them, or you can parse the string into a `DateTime` value and reformat it into a new string.

Example:

```
Dim source As String = "24/5/2009 3:40:00 AM"
Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(source, "d'/'M'/'yyyy h':'mm':'ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim result As String = d.ToString("M'/'d'/'yyyy h':'mm':'ss tt")
```

Or:

```
Dim source As String = "24/5/2009 3:40:00 AM"
Dim d As String() = source.Split("/".ToCharArray(), 3)
string result = d(1) + "/" + d(0) + "/" + d(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
   sql = "INSERT INTO emp(ID, firstname, lastname, DOB) VALUES(Null, '" & txtFirstName.Text.Trim & "','" & txtLastName.Text.Trim & "', '" & dpDOB.Value.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "');"

    mMySQLConnection.Open();
    comm = New MySqlCommand(sql, mMySQLConnection);

    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    mMySQLConnection.Close();
```