# How to convert english string date to portuguese string date

Tags: c#

How to convert english string date to portuguese string date in C# .Net?

I have a string: `2014-06-15` and I need to convert to `15-06-2014` (dd-MM-yyyy format)

Comment: hint:  searched here for "string date reformat" and had plenty to sift through.

Comment: DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yy")

http://stackoverflow.com/a/420633/512507

Answer (score 2):

```
String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", DateTime.Parse("2014-06-15")); // "15-06-2014"
```

Or

```
DateTime.Parse("2014-06-15").ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); // "15-06-2014"
```

String.Format can give you almost everything you need with the date parsing.

Taken from [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/). Examples:

```
// create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone


Specifier   DateTimeFormatInfo property       Pattern value (for en-US culture)
t           ShortTimePattern                  h:mm tt
d           ShortDatePattern                  M/d/yyyy
T           LongTimePattern                   h:mm:ss tt
D           LongDatePattern                   dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
f           (combination of D and t)          dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt
F           FullDateTimePattern               dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
g           (combination of d and t)          M/d/yyyy h:mm tt
G           (combination of d and T)          M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
m, M        MonthDayPattern                   MMMM dd
y, Y        YearMonthPattern                  MMMM, yyyy
r, R        RFC1123Pattern                    ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT' (*)
s           SortableDateTi­mePattern           yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss (*)
u           UniversalSorta­bleDateTimePat­tern  yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z' (*)
                                              (*) = culture independent



String.Format("{0:t}", dt);  // "4:05 PM"                         ShortTime
String.Format("{0:d}", dt);  // "3/9/2008"                        ShortDate
String.Format("{0:T}", dt);  // "4:05:07 PM"                      LongTime
String.Format("{0:D}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008"          LongDate
String.Format("{0:f}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008 4:05 PM"  LongDate+ShortTime
String.Format("{0:F}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 09, 2008 4:05:07 PM" FullDateTime
String.Format("{0:g}", dt);  // "3/9/2008 4:05 PM"                ShortDate+ShortTime
String.Format("{0:G}", dt);  // "3/9/2008 4:05:07 PM"             ShortDate+LongTime
String.Format("{0:m}", dt);  // "March 09"                        MonthDay
String.Format("{0:y}", dt);  // "March, 2008"                     YearMonth
String.Format("{0:r}", dt);  // "Sun, 09 Mar 2008 16:05:07 GMT"   RFC1123
String.Format("{0:s}", dt);  // "2008-03-09T16:05:07"             SortableDateTime
String.Format("{0:u}", dt);  // "2008-03-09 16:05:07Z"            UniversalSortableDateTime
```

Comment: -1 you're formatting a new instance of `DateTime`, OP needs to parse a string to a `DateTime` and then format it.

Comment: @Stijn, I gave the string Date right now. Will that work for you?

Comment: Yep, downvote removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateTime` `Parse` and `ToString()` methods :

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("2014-06-15");
var result = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Minor point - OP wanted "-" instead of "/".

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("2014-06-15").ToString("d", 
           CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-PT"));
```

This uses the settings from the specified culture.

Comment: Depending on the current culture of the computer running your code I think the `Parse` may have the opportunity parse incorrectly. It would be better to do `ParseExact` or specify the culture for the `Parse` too.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use `ParseExact`, there is also an overload of `Parse` with an `IFormatProvider` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can either hard-code the format using the built-in [`DateTime` format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var testDate = DateTime.Parse("2014-06-15");
Console.WriteLine(testDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")); // 02-06-2014
```

Or, you can use the [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.globalization.cultureinfo) class along with [the `DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload to force the string to use the system-specified format for that culture:

```
var testDate = DateTime.Parse("2014-06-15");
var usa = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
var portugal = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-PT");
var brazil = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");

Console.WriteLine(testDate.ToString("d", usa)); // 6/2/2014
Console.WriteLine(testDate.ToString("d", portugal)); // 02-06-2014
Console.WriteLine(testDate.ToString("d", brazil)); // 02/06/2014
```

Also, for reference, here is a site with all of the format strings for the `CultureInfo` class for each supported culture:

> http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/