# use C# to output date and time to XML file

Tags: c#, xml, datetime

I am writing a program in c# that serializes objects to XML

I am having trouble with the date and time fields, they do not produce the following output in XML:

```
2014-05-13T00:00:00
0000000T18:35:00
```

I have declared the fields as following in my program:

```
public DateTime startDate
public DateTime startTime
```

Can anyone help so that the date is correctly outputted to XML file?

Thank you

Comment: What is the 000000000T?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert an object to an XML string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447529/convert-an-object-to-an-xml-string)

Comment: Just curious: Why do you need to split Date and Time if they refer to the same event (start)?

Comment: It would really help if you could provide sample code, expected output and actual output...

Comment: You dont need 2 DateTime variables to store the date and time.

Comment: I ended up using this and it works a treat:

startDate = DateTime.TryParse("2014/5/13", out scheduleDate) ? scheduleDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : "";

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to declare startTime to get the input you want. Just parse your datetime like this:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2014, 5, 13, 18, 35, 0);
startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff");//2014-05-13T18:35:00.000000
```

You can also check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999827/how-to-convert-english-string-date-to-portuguese-string-date/23999889#23999889) regarding to formating datetime.

Comment: I ended up using this and it works a treat:

startDate = DateTime.TryParse("2014/5/13", out scheduleDate) ? scheduleDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : "";

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` represents both date and time, so really only one variable would be enough:

```
public DateTime startTimestamp;
```

You can then create the string representations you want from that single datetime value like this:

```
string dateValue = startTimestamp.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
```

Problem is that "00000000" is not a valid date, so you need to do your own formatting:

```
string timeValue = "00000000T" + startTimestamp.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

The question actually is why you want to store the (empty) time part and the (invalid) date part in your XML when you could just store either date and time within one value or date and time in separate values like this:

```
string dateTimeValue = startTimestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
string dateOnly = startTimestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
string timeOnly = startTimestamp.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the field    `startTime` is storing time with timezone then please note that the literal structure for  `xs:time` datatype is  
    `hh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]`.  
    `0000000T18:35:00` seems to be invalid.

Comment: I ended up using this and it works a treat:

startDate = DateTime.TryParse("2014/5/13", out scheduleDate) ? scheduleDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : "";

thanks for your help

Comment: Cool. I believe then you wanted to ignore time and just save Date information. If you wanted to include time it would be  `scheduleDate.ToString("R")` for including the timezone or  `scheduleDate.ToString("F")` without that.