# How to give a date Format to the sting parameter in query string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

I was wondering if someone can help me here. I want to give a date format  like this : `"MM/dd/yyyy"`
I know in query string all format should be int or string. this is my url.action:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new 
{ 
  page, 
  creationDate = ViewBag.Date.ToString(),  
  sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, 
  AccountIdFilter = ViewBag.AccountIdFilter 
}))
```

The problem is with `creationDate = ViewBag.Date.ToString()`. This is converted to a string but not in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. And this is my controller :

```
  public ActionResult Index(string accountIdFilter,DateTime? creationDate, int page=1, Sort sortOrder =Sort.Descending)        
        {
            int take = 2;
            DateTime date;
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = sortOrder == Sort.Descending ? Sort.Assending : Sort.Descending;
            ViewBag.AccountIdFilter = accountIdFilter;
            if (!creationDate.HasValue)
            {
                 date = DateTime.ParseExact("2020-05-08", "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else
            {

                date = DateTime.ParseExact(creationDate.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            ViewBag.Date = date;
            BankDepositHistoryListDTO data;
            try
            {                
                 data = BankDepositHistoryServices.GetAllByPagination(sortOrder, accountIdFilter, take, creationDate, page);                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex.ToString());
                data = BankDepositHistoryServices.GetAllByPagination(sortOrder, accountIdFilter, take, creationDate, 1);
                page = 1;
            }
            var result = data.BankDepositHistoriyItems;
            int count = data.Count;
            var resultPagedList = new StaticPagedList<BankDepositHistoryDTO>(result, page, take, count);
            return View(resultPagedList);            
        }
```

the problem is here :

```
 else
            {

                date = DateTime.ParseExact(creationDate.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
```

At that line I got this exception : `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`
the out put  for `creationDate.ToString()` is  `"5/8/2020 12:00:00 AM"` .
So what should I do?
With many thanks

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420623/how-to-convert-date-into-mm-dd-yy-format-in-c-sharp

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I edited that.

Comment: Well that changes the question. Now we need to know what `creationDate.ToString()` outputs

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I edited again.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan please if its possible don't mark it as duplicate

Comment: Have you tried using the overload in the linked answer?