# Wrong DateTime format

Tags: c#, datetime-format

When I run the following code in a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gpN72W), I get the output I expect:

```cs
var myDate = new DateTime(2019, 6, 1);
Console.WriteLine(myDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy")); 

// Output is: 06/01/19
```

But when I run the exact same code in a brand new C# Console application (.NET Framework 4.5.2) or in the [C# Interactive](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/C%23-Interactive-Walkthrough) window, I get this output:

`06-01-19`

Why does the Console app and the C# Interactive window replace `/` with `-` in the output? Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/420633/4416750) and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), I would expect the date to be delimited with `/` not `-`. In this example from Microsoft's documentation, it shows the output containing `/`:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("The current date and time: {0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz}", 
                   thisDate2); 
// The example displays the following output:
//    The current date and time: 06/10/11 15:24:16 +00:00
```

Comment: It depends on the culture settings of your machine

Comment: You missed [this bit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator) of the doc you linked.

Comment: @canton7 You are absolutely right. Doh!

Comment: Thanks Steve, canton7, Rango, and Joel Coehoorn for the fast and accurate answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with datetime format strings, the `/` character is special, just like `d`, `M`, or `y`. It means use the [system-defined date separator character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator).

So the system date separator at DotNetFiddle is `/`, but the separator on your system is `-`.

If you really always need the `/` character, this excerpt from the linked documentation will help:

> To change the date separator for a particular date and time string, specify the separator character within a literal string delimiter. For example, the custom format string `mm'/'dd'/'yyyy` produces a result string in which "/" is always used as the date separator.

Be careful with this. Over-riding the system and user's choices should not be done lightly. For example, I sometimes see people want to do this in order for format a date for use in an SQL command, and that is **never** okay; if you're formatting dates as strings for SQL, rather than using query parameters, you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: I was about to make my own answer with the literal string delimiter fix, but your edit beat me to it. I'll accept this answer when the site allows me to.

Comment: Good comment about being careful when overriding the culture settings. I am doing this simply to display a date in the format I want in a label in an MVC view so I think I'm okay on this one. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe that's okay. But if you can bind the date to the view as a System.DateTime, then ASP.Net can sometimes respect the browser's culture, and your users will see your date in the format matching the culture they're most comfortable with.

Comment: Fair point. I guess I'll stick with letting the culture settings decide how the delimiter is rendered. Thanks!

Comment: @LewsTherin If you can, use the [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) for display. In your case, use `"d"`. Other cultures get very annoyed when we force UK/US formatting on them.